# Как установить выбранный элемент во время создания fancytree

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте,

Использую плагин fancytree для отображения дерева. Нужно сразу после создания дерева установить активный элемент. В данный момент получаю

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

Построение дерева проваливается и дерево не отображается. Как правильно обратиться к дереву из события и установить активный элемент?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$("#fancyree_category-tree").fancytree( {
   "source":[{
      "key":1,"title":"Главная","folder":true,"expanded":true,"children":[{
        "key":2,"title":"Вторая","folder":true,"expanded":true,"children":[{
          "key":3,"title":"Третья","folder":true,"expanded":true
          }]
        }]
      }],
      "extensions":["dnd"],
      "activate":function(event, data){
                    window.location.href=window.location.origin+window.location.pathname+"?catid="+data.node.key;
                },
      "create":function(event, data){
                    $("#fancytree_category-tree").activateKey(2);
                }
   })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить Вашу строчку `$("#fancytree_category-tree").activateKey(2);` этой `$("#fancyree_category-tree").data('fancytree').tree.activateKey(2)`

Comment: Cannot read property 'tree' of undefined

Comment: @atom-22 Есть трудной путь :-) А именно для нода задать поле `active:true`      "key":2,"title":"Вторая","folder":true,"expanded":true, `active:true`, "children":[{
          "key":3,"title":"Третья","folder":true,"expanded":true
          }]